# Get the value of anchor using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="myTable_reports_view_paginate">
    <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="myTable_reports_view_previous">&lt;&lt;</a>
    <span>
        <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a>
        <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
    <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">33</a>
    </span>
    <a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="myTable_reports_view_next">&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

My question is how to get the value 33 using jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.paginate_button').last().text()
```

looks like you have updated the question, which makes the answer incorrect, so below is my updated answer.

```
$('#myTable_reports_view_paginate span > a.paginate_button').last().text()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** selector , to avoid `next` use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

```js
alert($('a.paginate_button:not(.next):last').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="myTable_reports_view_paginate">
  <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="myTable_reports_view_previous">&lt;&lt;</a>
  <span>
                        <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a>
                        <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
  <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">33</a>
  </span>
  <a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="myTable_reports_view_next">&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

You can also use `last()` and `not()`

```js
alert($('a.paginate_button').not('.next').last().text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="myTable_reports_view_paginate">
  <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="myTable_reports_view_previous">&lt;&lt;</a>
  <span>
                        <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a>
                        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a>
                        <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
  <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">33</a>
  </span>
  <a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="myTable_reports_view" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="myTable_reports_view_next">&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u for the great advice but when i am runing the code it get the blank in alert.

Comment: I have added jquery lib as well but still not working sir.

Comment: alert($('a.paginate_button').not('.next').last().text()) used this as well but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
$('.paginate_button:contains("33")').text()
```

Comment: $('.paginate_button:contains("33")').text()

Comment: I have try that one too but value is blank.

Comment: give me jsfiddle link

Comment: $('.paginate_button:contains("33")').text() try this one as well but not - Muhammad Atif

Comment: I dont have js Fiddle link - Muhammad Atif

Comment: Any Other solution sir because code is not working at my side.

Comment: $("#myTable_reports_view_paginate a:contains('33')").text()

Comment: Sorry Sir $("#myTable_reports_view_paginate a:contains('33')").text() used but not working.

Comment: Thanx you all user for helping...

Its is working...

$(function () {
      $("#myTable_reports_view_paginate a:contains('33')").text() == 33) {
            //coding...     
      }
});